# The type or namespace name 'Config' could not be found

Tags: asp.net

i'm try the asp.net code of Flexpaper here is the code got error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using lib;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;



public partial class setup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected String path_to_pdf2swf = @"C:\Program Files\SWFTools\";
    protected String path_to_pdf2json = @"C:\Program Files\PDF2JSON\";
    protected String pdf2swf_exec = "pdf2swf.exe";
    protected String pdf2json_exec = "pdf2json.exe";
    protected int step = 1;
    protected Config configManager;
```

Error

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Config' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 24:     protected String pdf2json_exec = "pdf2json.exe";
Line 25:     protected int step = 1;
Line 26:     protected Config configManager;
Line 27: 
Line 28:     private Boolean pdf2swf = false;
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: It means what it said, compiler don't know in what namespace `Config` is defined. Either add `using` statement or provide full namespace in declaration.

Comment: What is `Config` supposed to mean? If it is an existing class, make sure to address it by its full name including namespace, either by prefixing it or using a `using` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you wrote :
protected Config configManager;

here Config is not a data type that's why you getting this error.